# C# variable used but never assigned

Tags: c#

So I have been working on a program that calculates nearest and larger 3rd power to a number which is entered (if entered number is 20 then result is 27 because 3^3=27). However due to my lack of skills I have stumbled upon a problem. It seems that variable result is used but never assigned (even if its value is asigned to it in a for cycle) Here is the code:

```
namespace ConsoleApp6
{
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        Console.Write("Enter a number: ");
        int num = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());
        int result;
        for(int i = num; (i * i * i) >= 0; i--)
        {
            result = i * i * i;
        }
        Console.WriteLine("Nest 3rd pow. is: " + result);
        Console.WriteLine("Press any key to contiunue...");
        Console.ReadLine();
    }
 }
}
```

Thank you for your answers.

Comment: Which variable do you assert is not assigned? (Depending on what you mean by assigned) the compiler doesn't let this occur without flagging it up so if you've managed it, the problem needs reporting to Microsoft

Comment: `int result = 0;`

Comment: To solve it, declare `int result = 0` or some other integer. The compiler is giving you the error because there is a chance that your `for` loop is never entered and then `result` will never be initialized.

Comment: The compiler cannot know ahead of time that `result` will get a value.  What if the user enters -1?  You'll try to write `result` when it has no value.

Comment: @CaiusJard the variable result is never assigned according to my engine, if I assign result to 1 (at the declaration) it is going to print out 1

Comment: @RyanWilson Does not work the output will simply be the number I have assigned to it, no matter the imput

Comment: The compiler is telling you that there's a chance it won't get assigned (i.e. there's a chance you'll never get into the `for` loop).  It must be assigned a value for all possible paths.  See my previous comment for just one instance where it would not be assigned.

Comment: If you set `int result = 0` the `result` will be reassigned in your `for` loop

Comment: @MikeH Thanks, now I understand

Comment: If you entered 20 your loop start at 20 and check 20*20*20 >= 0 and set result 20^3 to 0*0*0>=0 (this also true ) and set your result to 0 and write to 0 to console, am I reading wrong ?

Comment: Your loop will currently iterate until `result` is always 0, if it runs.

Answer (score 2):

The comments have probably dealt with your issue (you didn't set a value for `result` when you created it, the compiler can foresee a scenario where no loop runs and there is never any assignment, but you always use it. A "use of unassigned local variable" error arises), but I wanted to point out that your program is some way off solving the advertised problem of finding the next larger int cube than the entered number

To solve this, cube root the entered number, round it up to the next integer and cube it

```
Math.Pow(Math.Ceiling(Math.Pow(num, 1.0/3.0)), 3.0);
```

As things stand, I'm not really sure what you're aiming to achieve with the loop, and it looks like it will run however many times needed to set the result to 0 (it loops until i is zero, result is 0). Perhaps you intended to start i from 2 and increment i until result was larger than num, but that seems less efficient than doing the calc directly

Answer (score 0):

One overall rule of good programming praxis is to initialize a variable on the declaration.

The compiler error says that you are using `result` when it has not been assigned. That's because in your `for loop` you can't predict that it will iterate at least one time (therefore there are scenarios where the variable is used without ever being assigned).

As have been mentioned before, this can be fixed by initializing the variable (0 is the standard)

```
int result = 0;
```